# What is caching auto configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching

The **Spring Boot** Framework simplifies the implementation of caching by auto-configuration support. What is caching auto-configuration means?

Comment: This is not a good question for Stack Overflow. Try https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Looking at how to config caching in a spring-boot app? Have a look here: [baeldung spring-cache-tutoria](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

In Spring boot you have annotations which takes care of all configuration. Like you can enable caching using @EnableCaching and add @Cacheable with details to cache output of a method and much more.

Read more about Spring boot caching here - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html